# wordpress - change "global" settings for all posts from order by date (timestamp) to order by post_name

Tags: database, wordpress

I am from germany. sorry for my bad english.
i wanna sort all posts "global" by post_name (slug) because all posts that are in my homepage need NOT sort by date (timestamp).

```
<?php
function order_posts_by_slug( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        // Display only 5 post for the original blog archive
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_name' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_posts_by_slug', 1 );
?>
```

This code works fine, because there is a main-query before. It goes fine also with e. g. if is_home). But when i call my category-sites (e. g. www.mysite.com/category/xy-category) it isnt ordered by trying is_category. but the best would be to order all my posts by my wish (e. g. order by post_name ).

Any ideas?

Comment: What's keeping you from using `is_category()`, or removing the second condition completely and just keeping `if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;`?

Comment: i tried to drop the if-condition. it works! Perhaps i made a syntax-mistake. BUT: in contrast to the other sides (is_home or is_search) the pagnation isnt working.

Comment: How did you insert the pagination? Since it should use $wp_query, it should reflect your changes in pre_get_posts just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As Janh2 mentioned, you can use `is_category()` in your condition:

```
<?php
     ....
    // change order on search results or on category pages
    if ( is_search() || is_category() ) {
        // Display only 5 post for the original blog archive
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_name' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        return;
    }
}
....
?>
```

the condition checks if you are in search result pages or in category pages